# ifelse function in R with OR operator

Tags: r, if-statement

I am struggling with a basic question involving using the OR operator in an if else statement:

```
q1 <-c("yes", "no", "yes", "no")
q2 <-c("no", "yes", "yes", "no")
df<-cbind(q1, q2)
```

I want to add a new column result which will be populated with 'yes' if either q1 or q2 have a yes in their respective columns.  So far I have:

```
df$result <- ifelse(df$q1=="yes" | df$q2=="yes", "yes", "no")
```

Could someone explain why it isn't working, and why I keep getting the atomic vector error when I referring to a specific dataframe column?

Comment: You might consider using booleans directly instead of strings; then you can have `df <- data.frame(q1 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), q2 = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)); df$result <- df$q1 | df$q2`

Comment: It may be worth adding the error text ("$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors") to your question to make it easier to find ...

Comment: Learn to use `str` so you can avoid confusing different types of data objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `cbind()` on two vectors gives you a matrix rather than a data frame; you can either use `cbind()` and then use `df[,"q1"]` (etc.) to access columns, or use `df <- data.frame(q1, q2)` to get a data frame, at which point your `df$q1` references will work. Using `data.frame()` is probably best practice unless you *know* you want a matrix (for doing actual linear algebra, or for computational efficiency in some particular cases).